Find the matrix with respect to the canonical basis of the orthogonal projection of $R^3$ on subspace $S$
Find the matrix with respect to the canonical basis of the orthogonal projection of $R^3$ on subspace $S=\text{span}{(1,0, -1),(0,1 ,-1)}$.
I have to get the orthogonal subspace ($S^⊥$), and that is the projection?
Do I have to write that base in terms of the canonical base of $R^3$ and that's how I get the matrix?
thanks

Can you recall the definition of orthogonal projection on a subspace ?

No, the orthogonal subspace $S^\perp$ is not the projection; one of these things is a subspace, and the other is a linear transformation. It is not clear what you mean by "that base", but there's no clear relationship between "getting that base in terms of the canonical base of $\Bbb R^3$" and finding the matrix of the transformation.

If you can get the matrix $Q$ of the orthogonal projection onto $S^\perp$ (which is relatively easy since $S^\perp$ is a one-dimensional subspace), then the matrix that your projection can be calculated as $P = I - Q$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

The final answer to your question is
$$
P = \frac 13 \pmatrix{2 & -1 & -1\-1 & 2 & -1\ -1 & -1 & 2}
$$

@BenGrossmann Thanks for the reply. ok, but I thought that the result we had to reach was Q, why is it necessary to use P= I-Q and where does that equation come from?

@ssj Do you understand that "the projection onto $S$" and "the projection onto $S^\perp$" are two different things? If so, then why do you think that they should have the same matrix?

Therefore, the first column of P could be obtained as $P_S$(v)= v- $P_S$$^⊥$(v), is this correct?

I don't know what you mean by that sentence. Are you talking about plugging in a specific vector $v$? If so, which vector $v$ would you be plugging in to get the first column specifically?
